# If current price breaks out the high of a range?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Whenever I code for `"if the current price (close) breaks out high[1]"` so like:

```
 if close > high[1]:
      strategy.entry("Go Long", strategy.long, qty=1)
```

it always enters at the close or the open of the next candle when I want it to go in as soon as the current price breaks above the high[1]. I've never been able to it figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strategy.entry()` will place a market order by default. You are looking for a limit order. For this, you should be using `limit` or `stop` arguments of the `strategy.entry()`.

> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Limit price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'limit', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'stop', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.

```
strategy.entry("Go Long", strategy.long, qty=1, stop=high[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit! It still waits for the candle that broke out to close and jumps in on the next one...

Answer (score 0):

If you want open position when price just pass previous high candle, add `calc_on_every_tick = true` to strategy function.

```
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)
```

Comment: I already have that on there... Maybe something wrong with my code? No matter which candle ([1] or [0]) seems to do the same thing.

```
   if (close[0] < open[0] and strategy.position_size == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed)
       entryHigh := high[0]

   if close > entryHigh
       strategy.entry("FirstRed", strategy.long, qty=1, limit = entryHigh)
```